# Change appearance of select tag to radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

Good morning,

I have a web page in which you can rate systems.

[image: Rate systems]

I created a javascript to dynamically add new systems to be evaluated and to remove them. The problem is that I have to manually change the radio buttons names, so they don't become one giant radio button.

When adding new buttons it's easy to just change the name of the new radio-buttons from radio-button-0 to radio-button-1. But, when removing, I have to rename all items, or there will be gaps (radio-button-0 and radio-button-2 exist, but not radio-button-1).

In the other hand, selects don't have to be renamed. They will just be selected in separate and I can check their value later as an array easily.

I was wondering if there's anyway to create a select item, but change its appearance so it will look like a radio button. Or if there's any easy way to create new radio-buttons without them grouping together (It also can be a jQuery approach).

I would rather not use [XForms Select1 tags](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Select1).

Thank you,

Comment: Why do you need to name them by number? Why cant you name them by the attribute label that you have instead if a name/label/attribute is required data.

Then there will be no gaps because you are using labels instead of numbers. Ofcourse this requires each label to be unique. But I dont see why anyone would like to add 2 labels/attributes with exactly the same name, so you could do a validation on that.

Comment: That's a good idea, I could name them based on the system id, then I could guarantee, with js, that all systems are always different. Then there would be no two radio buttons with the same name. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy it helped. I posted it as an answer instead of a comment so please accept it as the correct answer if that was the way you solved your problem/question/issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only things you can style about an a `<select>` + `<option>` are `background-color` and `color`.

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is probably to use some sort of a plugin.  Either that, or you could possibly write some sort of script that populates X amount of radio buttons with an incrementing name to go under each tag with the class Y.

Comment: Its definitely not rendered by the OS. Each browser have their own style for each control. That is obviously an incorrect statement because Safari on Windows will still draw a radio button the same way as Safari on Mac.

Comment: @catalyst294 Maybe you're right.  Regardless, you can only change the `background-color` and `color`, whatever the reason. I'll edit out that statement since I can't confirm or deny its validity.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to name them by number? Why cant you name them by the attribute label that you have instead if a name/label/attribute is required data.

Then there will be no gaps because you are using labels instead of numbers. Ofcourse this requires each label to be unique. But I dont see why anyone would like to add 2 labels/attributes with exactly the same name, so you could do a validation on that.